# Error on Alter Table-valued Function with Native Compilation in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, function

I have the following script that alters my native compiled function. I want it to return a Table. I am also altering from single statement into multi statement. so I am changing `returns` to `begin atomic`.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MovieSimularity]
(   
    @movieID int
)
RETURNS @result Table (movieID int, distance int)
WITH Native_Compilation, SCHEMABINDING
as
Begin ATOMIC WITH (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'English')
--begin

    declare @m int
    declare @countZero int
    declare @r Table (movieID int, distance int)
    declare cur cursor local for 
        select movieID
        from dbo.Movies
        where movieID != @movieID and dbo.CompareMovieHashes(@movieID, movieID) = 1

    open cur
    fetch next from cur into @m
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        insert into @r 
            select @m, dbo.MovieEuclideanDistance(@movieID,@m) as distance

        set @countZero = (select count(*) from @r where distance = 0)
        if(@countZero > 5)
            break

        fetch next from cur into @m
    end
    close cur
    deallocate cur

    return
        select top(5) *
        from @r
        order by distance   
end
```

The execution gives me the following errors:

```
Msg 487, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MovieSimularity, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 7]
An invalid option was specified for the statement "CREATE/ALTER FUNCTION".
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MovieSimularity, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MovieSimularity, Line 44 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
```

I don't know what is the problem. Please Help

Comment: What's the point of a TVF that uses *cursors*? There's nothing slower than a cursor. Trying to compile it natively isn't going to make it any faster. What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, there are simpler and faster ways to do it using queries

Comment: For example, the two cursors are essentially an `INSERT SELECT FROM`. Euclidian distance - that sounds like a spatial function (hint). Finding the top 5 matches just needs a `TOP 5` clause in the `SELECT`, or a `ROW_NUMBER()` to calculate row numbers up to 5

Comment: @Panagiotiskanavos Thank you a lot. I did not know about the slow cursor. I don't want to use top 5 because I am using order by and my minimum value is zero, so I don't want to calculate all euclidian distances. When it finds five zero is enough.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I removed atomic with... now I have only the first error.

Answer (score 1):

> BEGIN ATOMIC is part of the ANSI SQL standard. SQL Server supports
>   atomic blocks at the top-level of natively compiled **stored procedures**,
>   as well as for natively compiled, **scalar user-defined functions**. For
>   more information about these functions, see Scalar User-Defined
>   Functions for In-Memory OLTP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/atomic-blocks-in-native-procedures

Atomic is not supported by Table-Valued functions (as per the docs), only be Scalar-Valued functions.

What is wrong with this query? Why do you need the cursor?

```
DECLARE @movieID INT = 1;
SELECT TOP(5)
      movieID
    , dbo.MovieEuclideanDistance(@movieID,m.movieID) AS distance
FROM
    dbo.Movies
WHERE
    movieID != @movieID
    AND dbo.CompareMovieHashes(@movieID, movieID) = 1
ORDER BY
    distance
```

Here is a solution to your 0 distance problem without using cursors or loops. Adjust it to your needs.

```
DECLARE
    @rowsToCalculate INT = 5
  , @currentX DECIMAL(8,5)
  , @currentY DECIMAL(8,5)
;

-- Get the current movie's X and Y coordinates
SELECT
  , @currentX = CoordX
  , @currentY = CoordY
FROM
  dbo.Movies
WHERE
  MovieID = @movieID
;

-- First get the list with distance 0 (x and y coordinates are equal)
INSERT INTO @result (MovieID int, Distance int)
SELECT TOP(@rowsToCalculate)
    MovieID
  , 0 AS Distance
WHERE
  CoordX = @currentX
  AND CoordY = @currentY
  AND MovieID != @movieID
  AND dbo.CompareMovieHashes(@movieID, MovieID) = 1
;

-- Figure out how many records do we need and get them if there is any.
SET @rowsToCalculate = @rowsToCalculate - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @result);

IF (@rowsToCalculate > 0) BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @result (MovieID int, Distance int)
  SELECT TOP(@rowsToCalculate)
      movieID
    , dbo.MovieEuclideanDistance(@movieID,m.movieID) AS distance
  FROM
    dbo.Movies
  WHERE
    movieID != @movieID
    AND dbo.CompareMovieHashes(@movieID, MovieID) = 1
    AND (CoordX != @currentX OR CoordY != @currentY)
  ORDER BY
    Distance
END
```

Comment: I don't want to use top 5 because I am using order by and my minimum value is zero, so I don't want to calculate all euclidean distances. When it finds five zero is enough processing

Comment: I removed atomic with... now I have only the first error.

Comment: Interesting thinking, but let me point out that using cursor is the most inefficient way to do this. SQL is not a procedural language and SQL Server is not a procedural environment. For the error message: read it, interpret it, check the docs and you'll find out. You have only 2 options declared, one of them cannot be used for TVFs

Comment: Edit has been added to solve the 0 distance problem.